# How to improve python regex pattern search's matching speed in extracting information from filenames in subfolders of a main folder?

Tags: python, pathlib

Suppose I have a main folder that contains 5 subfolders of slightly different names, then each of the subfolders contains a single CSV file (Could be multiple as well). I made a program to get the basenames of each CSV. Using list comprehension, "Path.is_file()", and "Path.rglob()" read from each subfolder. Then I used "os.path.basename()" and "re.search()" to first get the filenames in a list of strings and then search through each name to match patterns provided in the code, and return the matched names. By researching the syntax rule of the [search pattern for regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), I don't quite understand how it works but I found something that works for the code below. Is there another way for the syntax because what if the numbers of the digits in the search pattern varies? The format of the folders and filenames are as follows:

Main folder path:

> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData'

Subfolder paths:

> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1234_G12345-123123_45C_01-01-2023'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1256_G12356-456456_25C_01-01-2023'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1278_G12378-345345_65C_01-01-2023'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1290_G12390-789789_85C_01-01-2023'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1291_G12391-234567_75C_01-01-2023'

Basenames of each file in each subfolder (1 file in each subfolder here):

> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1234_G12345-123123_45C_01-01-2023\B1234_G12345-123123_45C_01-01-2023.csv'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1256_G12356-456456_25C_01-01-2023\B1256_G12356-456456_25C_01-01-2023.csv'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1278_G12378-345345_65C_01-01-2023\B1278_G12378-345345_65C_01-01-2023.csv'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1290_G12390-789789_85C_01-01-2023\B1290_G12390-789789_85C_01-01-2023.csv'
> 'C:\Desktop\Users\myname\TestData\B1291_G12391-234567_75C_01-01-2023\B1291_G12391-234567_75C_01-01-2023.csv'

My code is as follows:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import re
import time

start_time = time.time()
def get_datafiles_in_subfolder(root: Path):
    paths = list(filter(lambda file: file.is_file(), root.rglob('*.csv')))
    names = [os.path.basename(path) for path in paths]
    
    return paths, names

data_root = Path('C:\\Desktop\\Users\\myname\\TestData')
paths, names = get_datafiles_in_subfolder(data_root)
for name in names:
    B_ID = re.search('[A-Z]\d{4}', name).group()
    G_ID = re.search('[A-Z]\d{5}(-)\d{6}', name).group()
    Temperature = re.search('\d{2}C', name).group()
    print(f'B_ID is: {B_ID}', end = '\n')
    print(f'G_ID is: {G_ID}', end = '\n')
    print(f'The temperature is: {Temperature})
end_time = time.time()
print(f"The program's run time is {end_time - start_time}s")
```

In the above code, I was able to get the ID that starts with a "B", the ID that starts with a "G" after it, and the temperature value of each basename of the CSV file. But this is very inefficient
for just 5 files. The runtime comes out to be 0.011073112487792969s or 1.1ms-ish, what should I do to improve the code to make the run time faster? What other packages and functions can I use to achieve the same results? Because this code may need to handle thousands of folders in the future.

Comment: Do you need `paths` variable in further processing?

Comment: Not after the for loop

Comment: *Not after* means "yes" or "no" using of it?

Comment: Before the for loop, yes. After the for loop, no.

Answer (score 1):

Optimize regex matching on path *basenames*:

```
for name in names:
    B_ID, G_ID, temp = re.search(r'([A-Z]\d{4})_([A-Z]\d{5}-\d{6})_(\d{2}C)', name).groups()
    print(f'B_ID is: {B_ID}', end = '\n')
    print(f'G_ID is: {G_ID}', end = '\n')
    print(f'The temperature is: {temp}')
```

---

Sample output:

```
B_ID is: B1234
G_ID is: G12345-123123
The temperature is: 45C
B_ID is: B1256
G_ID is: G12356-456456
The temperature is: 25C
B_ID is: B1278
G_ID is: G12378-345345
The temperature is: 65C
B_ID is: B1290
G_ID is: G12390-789789
The temperature is: 85C
B_ID is: B1291
G_ID is: G12391-234567
The temperature is: 75C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract multiple numbers from a file name with only one regex by using [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
B(\d+)_G(\d+-\d+)_(\d+)C
```

You then can extract `B_ID` using [`.group(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group), `G_ID` using `.group(2)` and temperature using `.group(3)`.

Quoted from your question:

> what if the numbers of the digits in the search pattern varies?

The `\d+` parts will match one or more digits, while `\d{6}` will only match *exactly* 6 digits. You can also consider [compiling that regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) outside the loop and use the compiled regex to match.

Comment: What does the minus "-" syntax after the first "+" stand for in G(\d+-\d+)? I looked it up in the syntax rule but could not find its meaning.

Comment: I got it, it's a dashed line.